# How to add a string array object in Date list array object list

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array which contains two object in it. I am binding that array to select html. My question is that i want to add first item as select date. How i can achieve this?

```
    function Preparelist(v) {
        var dateList= v;
        var q = { ID: 0, Name: "Select Date" };
        dateList.unshift(q);
        return dateList;
    }
```

I am unable to add string item to date array object. Please suggest. Thanks !

0 select date

1 10 july 2010

2 20 aug 2010

this above is my list which contains date.But i want to add 1st item as string to it like client can see select date as first option.

Comment: "I am unable to add string item to date array object." could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Can you addd a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: This is your mind? https://jsfiddle.net/5yL31u00/ Open Firebug with Console tab to see resultt.

Comment: my select list contains date.. I want to add string to it. like select date.